# Deleting periodic task for celery scheduler in `settings.py` will not delete the actual task

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Is there a way of deleting periodic task or removing the cache in Django Celery? Commenting out the code or deleting the corresponding code segment that schedules the task does not delete the actual task.

```
""" Commenting out, or deleting both entries from the code base doesn't do anything
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=2),
        'args': (2, 2)
    },
    'add-every-30-seconds2': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'args': (2, 6)
    },
}
"""
```

I tried `celery -A my_proj purge` but the periodic tasks still happens. I am using RabbitMQ as my broker

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [celery guide to periodic tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) and the [celery management guide](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#management-command-line-utilities-inspect-control).

inspect active: List active tasks

```
$ celery -A proj inspect active
```

inspect scheduled: List scheduled ETA tasks

```
$ celery -A proj inspect scheduled
```

control disable_events: Disable events

```
$ celery -A proj control disable_events
```

Alternatively, try the GUI management systems available in the management guide.

EDIT: Purge will only remove the messages, not the task itself.

Comment: All of these command doesn't remove the schedule job from the database

Answer (score 0):

Delete the task in the djcelery admin screen to remove it from the database.

Comment: How do you access `admin/djcelery` ? I am getting 403 error despite being able to access `admin/`